# PDO(prepare) analisa quantidade de caracteres?

Tags: php, pdo

A minha pergunta é simples: Imagine que tenho uma tabela `Nome` e nela, um atributo `nome` que é um `varchar(10)`. Se eu utilizar o comando `$preparado = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Nome(nome) VALUES('euTenhoMaisDeDezLetras')");` vai retornar algum erro por ultrapassar o limite? o que aconteceria se eu fizesse `$preparado->execute();`?

Comment: ele ira inserir so os 10 primeiros caracteres e o resto da palavra não sera inserido

Comment: Você está perdendo 90% da utilidade do prepare ao não fazer binding de variáveis na query...

Comment: eu não utilizei o bindParam() pro exemplo ficar mais rápido de entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varchar por padrão tem o valor variável, ou seja, ocupando somente aquilo que for inserido. Como você pode observar, o número correspondente dentro de varchar(n) é a quantidade de caracteres suportada, é essencial que você trate antes de realizar a inserção da informação no banco, visto que o máximo definido por você é 10.
Aconselho a utilizar a função php **strlen()**.

Mais sobre o tamanho do varchar [Varchar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296749/usar-varchar255-para-todos-os-campos-ou-ficar-escolhendo-o-melhor-tamanho-para)

Mais sobre [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

```
<?php

$str = 'euTenhoMaisDeDezLetras';

if (strlen($str) <= 10) {
    // todo o código anterior
    $preparado->execute();
} else {
    // tratar caso for maior que 10
}
```

Comment: Obrigado ^^ minha dúvida era mais sobre se era preciso tratar, ou se o prepare já fazia isso por mim

Comment: Toda e qualquer informação é essencial que você, independente se for tamanho, além do tipo do dado que está inserindo, até porque você não irá querer um erro por um usuário tentar inserir uma data num campo int não é mesmo, forte abraço.